# How do I set up ggplot dimensions to automatically match the Quarto Tufte layout (plot area in body column, legend area in margin column)?

Tags: ggplot2, legend, margins, quarto, tufte

I use Quarto for my laboratory notebooks (my handwriting isn't very readable).
I find the Tufte layout very suitable for this purpose.

I am trying to automatically fit ggplots into it with a specific idea.
My aim is to fit the plot area into the body column and the legend area into the margin column.

[image]

Basically I want to align green line with orange line automatically.

I can do this by manually adjusting the dimensions for plots, but this only works for one format (pdf or HTML). Changing formats requires changing parameters. Also it breaks with more complicated legends (most of my plots...), and those plots require plotp by plot adjustments.

I have also tried separating the plot and its legend into separate entities and plotting them with different parameters. Like this:

```
#| message: false
#| echo: false
#| warning: false

plot1b <- cowplot::get_legend(plot1)
plot1a <- plot1 +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

```
#| message: false
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-column: body

plot(plot1a)
```

```
#| message: false
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-column: margin

plot(plot1b)
```

Problems with this approach:

1. The plot and its legend are not always vertically aligned (especially when knitting to pdf - sometimes even not on the same page).
   [image]
2. The legend is plotted with default theme.

Part of my heading looks like this:

```
format:
    pdf:
      tbl-cap-location: margin
    html: 
      css: rj.css
      self-contained: true
      grid: 
        margin-width: 300px
lang: pl
reference-location: margin
citation-location: margin
cap-location: margin
mainfont: Calibri
```